# Singles net at ATP

Tags: tennis, atp

Why they don't use a singles net at the ATP Finals. Also on other big tournaments they often use the doubles net.
Is there a rule, when a turnament is supposed to have a singles net or is it a decision if every tournament?

Comment: They play doubles as well on them, why would it be better to have to take out the posts and nets and redo them between singles and doubles

Comment: A "Singles net" can also be a doubles net with sticks placed in the right spots on the sides. That's how it's done at nearly every professional tournament in the world, including the ATP finals.

Comment: @aqwert: true, but I remember in Gstaad (ATP250) the changed the net for doubles and singles until 10 years ago. And e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-AQC8Bbvhs in Wimbledon, they have singles net on the center court, when singles are played. So my question is, if is there a rule when a turnament should change the nets.

Comment: @chloese . I don't think there is a rule apart from the rule where the net needs to be a certain height on the ends (and therefore use a stick) and a certain height at the middle. If the tournament wants to go through the trouble then they can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule for which net to use. It is because doubles are played on the same tournament (venue) at the same time. It is easier to just place sticks under the net for singles rather than changing the whole net.